Are there any alternatives to online editors like Overleaf?
I have a .tex document that needs to be compiled with lualatex and I wish it could be done somewhere else besides Overleaf. I've tried the most popular solutions from here, but they either don't allow you to choose an engine, or they don't support packages.

Welcome! Can you not compile offline?

It will depend on what you need.... texlive.net can run lualatex and is has a complete texlive distribution, so almost all packages:  https://texlive.net/run?%25!TEX%20lualatex%0A%5Cdocumentclass%7Barticle%7D%0A%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0Atest%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D

there are several online systems, or you can self host the open source version of overleaf or you can (as I guess most of us do) just install tex locally and use that? What is your actual requirement?

How can I insert an external image \includegraphics in texlive.net? @David Carlisle

And what do you mean by "they don't support packages"?  I'd be surprised if they didn't have the more popular packages.  You didn't mention including external files in your original question.  And to get back to the start, why can't you use Overleaf?

you can not,unless you self host (it's all open source)
